# Oracle parameter naming conventions

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, naming-conventions

I understand that the naming convention for parameters in Oracle stored procedures are to prefix the parameters with 'p_', but is it allowed to use the @ symbol in Oracle in the way you would for Sql Server and Sybase?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Identifier must start with a letter.

---

**EDIT :**
Of course, you can use quoted identifiers with `@` inside if you like it very much:

```
function f("@parameter" int) return int is
begin
   return "@parameter" + 1;
end;
```